# centos problem while typing

Tags: linux, centos, terminal

I'm newbie to linux system and I use centos 6. I wanted to check the Ip address while configuring something. Instead of typing "ifconfig", I type "if config" and then the terminal becoming like the following picture. How could I exit this.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` is a keyword to the shell. You can either complete the syntactical construct, for example by typing `then true ; fi`, or just type control-c to break back to the normal prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much for helpful knowledge